# How to construct a flag manifold / flag variety?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geometric-algebras

I'm learning about flag manifolds and I'm trying to understand it better with an example.  My goal is to construct a flag manifold that will be a collection of 2 flags- `xy, yx`.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra)) I understand that the definition of a flag is that it's an increasing sequence of subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space V. So in the vector `xy`, `y` needs to contain `x`, and in the vector `yx`, `x` needs to contain `y`.

How can I construct it with simple vectors? Say, `x = [1,2]`, `y = [5,6]`. That is, what will `xy` or `yx` be equal to in a vector form?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Your notation is not standard for mathematics, so it's a little hard (for me) to understand exactly what you're asking. Probably you don't want specific vectors, but if we're working in the plane, something like $V_{1}$ the line spanned by $(1, 2)$ and $V_{2}$ the entire plane. The ordered pair $(V_1,V_2)$ is a _flag_. The _flag variety_ for the plane is the set of all such sequences of subspaces together with a notion of "nearness" or or "open set".

Comment: Thanks for the help! You're right, I'm actually coming from a computer science background (hence the notations). I actually do want specific vectors as I'm trying to code it. Basically, I'm trying to code the flags `xy` and `yx` as a combinations of subspaces of `x` and `y`. Does that make a little more sense?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The term "combination" isn't standard here. Does `xy` refer to the "sum", i.e., the set of linear combinations generated by vectors in `x` and/or `y` (a.k.a., the _span_ of `x` and `y`)? (I'm guessing not, since you distinguish `xy` and `yx`....) If not, how do you view `x`, e.g., does it stand for a specific type of data structure?

Comment: Ah I see. Really appreciate the help by the way. So, if we say that `x` and `y` represent 2 vectors, if I understand correctly (and please correct me if I'm wrong), there should be a difference between the flags `xy` and `yx`. By `xy` I mean `y` following `x`. Not sure if `x,y` is a better notation for that. The way I would view `x` in computer science /coding would simple be a vector form such as `[1,2]` for 2D vector, `[5,6,7]` for 3D, etc. where the first value is x dimension, then y, then z, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$This may not be an answer so much as a glossary based on clarifications in the comments.

---

If $V$ is a $k$-dimensional real vector space for some $k \geq 1$, and if $(x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{k}) = (x_{i})_{i=1}^{k}$ is an *ordered basis* of $V$, there is an *induced flag* $(V_{1}, \dots, V_{k}) = (V_{j})_{j=1}^{k}$ defined by $V_{j} = \Span(x_{i})_{i=1}^{j}$, the set of linear combinations of the first $j$ vectors in the ordered basis.

If we take $x = (1, 2)$ and $y = (5, 6)$, then $xy$ is the flag in the plane with $V_{1} = \Span(x)$—the set of scalar multiples of $(1, 2)$—and $V_{2} = \Reals^{2}$. Similarly, $yx$ is the flag in the plane with $V_{1} = \Span(y)$ and $V_{2} = \Reals^{2}$.

---

From a coding perspective, there's not much to say generally except the code presumably needs to supply an ordered list of ordered lists, e g., `[[1,1,1], [1,2,3], [-1,0,0]]` (caution: I don't speak Python), and needs to have some way of constructing, storing, and working with subspaces (sets of linear combinations).

Comment: I think I'm starting to get this. So the ordered list will correspond to V1 = Span(x)? i.e the set of scalar multiples of (1,2)? How would I represent the entire plane (V2)?

Comment: Almost: The _first element_ of the list spans the one-dimensional subspace $V_{1}$; the _first two_ elements span the two-dimensional subspace $V_{2}$, and so forth. The issue of representing the plane (the set of linear combinations $c_1x_1 + c_2x_2$) is the responsibility of whatever code handles flags. Or conversely, in order to write code to represent flags, it's highly desirable to have code to represent subspaces. That isn't mathematically difficult, but does require Gaussian elimination or the equivalent.